How can I use fragments with Apollo server's integration testing?
I am performing integration testing on an Apollo GraphQL server using executeOperation as described in Apollo's documentation. I'm new to using fragments, but if I understand correctly, I can define fragments in .gql files in order to share them across clients--an iOS client and a React client, for example. I want to extend the use of fragments to my testing such that when I write queries to pass to executeOperation I can use the fragments I've already defined in the .gql files. Has anyone found a way to do this?
P.S. I understand that the root cause is that fragments aren't part of the schema that the server defines, but I'm just looking for a workaround to this problem so that I can avoid code duplication.

A .gql file, as you're describing it, is just a text file. You can just read the file and use its contents:
Here's a hypothetical testQueries.ts file that has ALL of your queries all in a single document.
import fs from 'node:fs';

// load the fragments
const fragments = fs.readFileSync('fragments.gql', 'utf8');


export const testQueries = `gql
  #########################
  # Fragments
  #########################
  ${fragments}
  
  #########################
  # Queries
  #########################

  # User by ID
  query UserById($userId: ID!) {
    userById(id: $userId) {
      ... on User {
        ...UserFields
      }
    }
  }

  # Account by ID
  query AccountById($accountId: ID!) {
    accountById(id: $accountId) {
      ... on Account {
        ...AccountFields
      }
    }
  }
`;

And now, from one of your test files, you can run one of those specific operations:
import { testQueries } from './testQueries';

it('should load a user by id', async () => {
  const response = await testServer.executeOperation({
    query: testQueries,
    variables: {
      userId: '123'
    },
    operationName: 'UserById'
  });
  expect(response.errors).toBeUndefined();
  expect(response).toMatchSnapshot();
})

